# Infinite power tower for $x > e^{1/e}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, tetration, power-towers

For $x>0$, let $\tau_0 = 1$ and $\tau_{n+1} = x^{\tau_n}$. The infinite power tower of $x$ is then $\tau = \tau(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \tau_n$. It is well known that $\tau$ exists and is finite for $x \in \left[\frac{1}{e^e}, e^{\frac{1}{e}}\right]$. What I am wondering is:

1. How can one show $\lim_n \tau_n = \infty$ for $x > e^{\frac{1}{e}}$? It seems true from numerical experiments but should it be possible to prove this using elementary estimates? It is trivial by induction if $x \ge 2$ but I'm not sure how to push the proof up to $e^{\frac{1}{e}}$.
2. Intuitively, it is clear that if $x$ is really small, since $x^x \to 1$ as $x\to 0$, then $\tau_n$ should oscillate between $x$ and $1$. Is it true that if $x < \frac{1}{e^e}$, then there are two distinct positive real numbers $a=a(x), b=b(x)$ such that if $(\tau_{n_k})$ is a convergent sub-sequence of $(\tau_n)$, then $\lim_k \tau_{n_k} \in \left\{a, b\right\}$? Again, numerical experiments suggest so but I don't know how to proceed for the general proof.

Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: Please, use MathJax also in the title.

Comment: @jjagmath sorry did not notice it - done.

Comment: Could you try to study the function $t \mapsto x^t$ for fixed $x$? This should give you some results

Comment: @JulesBesson Could you elaborate on that? I see how, e.g., a study of the fixed points of the function you proposed imply the convergence (possibly coupled with a study $t \mapsto t^{\frac{1}{t}}$), but I'm not sure how it can be used to infer, e.g., divergence.

Comment: [Exponentials Reiterated](http://eretrandre.org/rb/files/Knoebel1981_158.pdf)